# Statics Reactions

Tags: statics

[image]

I'm trying to do this problem using components but I'm having trouble. I see no reason why I can't use this to solve. Maybe I got one of my variable wrong? Can some one help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let $\sum M_A = 0$, $T = 500*3.464/6 = 288.7$ lbs

$\sum F_x = 0$, $R_{Ax} = -T = -288.7$ lbs

$\sum F_y = 0$, $R_{Ay} = -500$ lbs

Note, when rolling up, the contact with point "B" is lost, thus $R_B$ is zero.

Comment: isn't the reaction at A variable depending where you are in the lift/pull?  If this is the case, wouldn't the maximum reaction be sqrt(2*500^2)?

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, the moment arm of rope changes, with the shortest at the beginning (max effort), then on final, the arm equals the diameter that requires the least effort.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have done is correct. The only thing extra you have to do is set reaction @B to '0' because when the ball lifts up from the ground, there will not be any contact with point B (or any point on the ground below for that matter). So, the expression for tension T becomes,
$$T = \frac{Mg.x}{6}$$
x is equal to 3.464 ft in your case.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is set the reaction at B as zero. This reduces the number of unknowns to 3 and you will be able to drop one of the 4 equations constraints (I would drop the equilibrium of moments around B).